# How to automatically bind string into ObjectId in controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core, model-binding

I am using mongodb and its ObjectId which is similar to Guid .NET type (its a struct). I want to be able to automatically bind ObjectId directly from path parameter in an API. I have working model binder that looks like this:

```cs
public class ObjectIdModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.FieldName);
        bindingContext.Result = ObjectId.TryParse(result.FirstValue, out var objectId) 
               ? ModelBindingResult.Success(objectId) 
               : ModelBindingResult.Failed();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and I can use it like this:

```cs
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetData([FromRoute, ModelBinder(typeof(ObjectIdModelBinder)] ObjectId id)
    {
        //do something
    }
```

How can I use it with model binder provider so that I dont have to specify the binder all the time for every endpoint? Is it something that is really unsupported for value types?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it didn't work before but this binder provider works in the end:

```cs
public class ObjectIdModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder? GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context) => context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(ObjectId) 
          ? new ObjectIdModelBinder() 
          : null;
}
```

Then register it like this:

```cs
services.AddControllers(options =>
     {
        options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new ObjectIdModelBinderProvider());
     });
```